# cs50 :( buy handles valid purchase expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found

Tags: cs50, finance

A problem appears to me and I do not know where it came from. I converted everything to float and it did not work. I tried to search for a solution but I could not find it. It is only in this function.

:( buy handles valid purchase
expected to find "112.00" in page, but it wasn't found

my code if can any one see it and tell me how fixed

code{

def buy():

```
if request.method == "POST":
    symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()
    shares = request.form.get("shares")

    if not symbol:
        return apology("must provide symbol", 400)
    elif not shares or not shares.isdigit() or int(shares) <= 0:
        return apology("must provide a positive integer number of shares", 400)

    quote = lookup(symbol)
    if quote is None:
        return apology("symbol not found", 400)

    price = quote["price"]
    total_cost = int(shares) * price
    cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=session["user_id"])[0]["cash"]

    if cash < total_cost:
        return apology("not enough cash", 400)

    # Update users table
    db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - :total_cost WHERE id = :user_id",
                total_cost=total_cost, user_id=session["user_id"])

    # Add the purchase to the history table
    db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (user_id, symbol, shares, price) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :shares, :price)",
                user_id=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, price=price)

    flash(f"Bought {shares} shares of {symbol} for {usd(total_cost)}!")
    return redirect("/")
else:
    return render_template("buy.html")
```

}

i dont know i try check the code but still not work

Comment: The issue likely isn't with your buy code, per se, but with the code for `index.html`, and displaying the user's accounts on that page.  Your account summary table needs to show the current value of each stock held, and use the provided `usd` Jinja filter for proper formatting. Check50 is buying 4 shares of a stock at exactly $28.00/share, so it expects the account summary to show exactly $112.00 as the value of that stock.  It will then sell two shares for a total remaining value of $56.00.

Answer (score 0):

in index.html just make like he want display total value and his my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4QGl.png)

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update? In either case, please don't post images of text. Use a code block instead.